# How do I activate docker?

Tags: gnome, docky, openbox, dock

I'm using Openbox (because the gnome3 GNOME shell and Unity were both making me c-r-a-z-y, not because I don't have hardware) and want to install a dock. I've heard good things about Docker and Docky both, but I don't know how to activate either. I'm running Gnome-do already and installed Docker. Now what?

Comment: Have you tried the [Openbox FAQ](http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:FAQ) or [Docky documentation](http://wiki.go-docky.com/index.php?title=Documentation) pages? This is usually better with something that is not part of a standard Ubuntu install.

Comment: Is this OpenBox + LXDE (aka Lubuntu) or OpenBox + Gnome?

Comment: @fossfreedom OpenBox + Gnome

Comment: @TomBrossman That'd be fair if either actually had an answer. I'm starting from zero, all the documentation I've found (there's more) starts from 1.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, are you looking for an answer? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: I'd still love an answer, actually.

Comment: If you're still looking for setting up a lightweight openbox desktop, check out the youtube link in my profile.  I show you how to set up an openbox desktop from scratch, including using Docky, which starts up on login.  I have a few videos on lightweight custom installs.  I later switched to Plank because it's slightly lighter.

Answer (score 0):

In you home directory there is a folder `.config` inside is another folder for Openbox.
Inside it create a file titled `autostart`, put what ever commands you want Openbox to run in it.

*Do NOT mark it executable*.

It works just like a sh script. I use mine to run zenity, and give me a dialog box to choose a session. These sessions can be anything you like idesk, Cairo Dock, Docky, Steam big picture mode, or whatever your little heart desires, but remember this isn't a shell script it just works similarly.

If you want to use it in this manner you have to make other scripts to compliment it, such as a separate script to load everything for Docky, and another one for Cairo Dock, Steam etc.